# HTACCESS URL Variable Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Looking to rewrite a URL and can't seem to get it working.

Example URL:

```
http://www.example.com/find/agency.php?agency=33524&name=happy-example
```

Ideal, rewritten URL:

```
http://www.example.com/find/agency/happy-example
```

One of the many attempted rewrites:

```
RewriteRule ^/([.]+)/([.]+)$ agency.php?agency=$1&name=$2

RewriteRule ^/([.]+)/([.]+)/$ agency.php?agency=$1&name=$2
```

Even if the removal of the "agency=" variable isn't possible, I still can't seem to make this URL write out the variables - am I approaching the rewrite backwards?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a rewrite condition to catch the query string before doing the rewrite.

For example something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^agency=33524&name=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^find/agency.php$ find/agency/%1? [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your rule. However to get a URL like this.

```
http://www.example.com/find/33524/happy-example
```

You would need to use a rewrite like below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^find/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /agency.php?agency=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a lazy modifier for the symbol matching (currently `([.]+)` will match everything )

```
RewriteRule ^/([.]+?)/([.]+?)$ agency.php?agency=$1&name=$2
RewriteRule ^/([.]+?)/([.]+?)/$ agency.php?agency=$1&name=$2
```

You can also combine these into one rule

```
RewriteRule ^/([.]+?)/([.]+?)[/]{0,1}$ agency.php?agency=$1&name=$2
```

This does not include whatever flags you would need depending on your particular case